# Transform Date to SimpleDateFormat

Tags: java, datetime, localization

I'm getting an XMLGregorianCalendar from a rest service. I need to localize the months depending on the language. I've read that the best way to localize a date is by using the SimpleDateFormat class. The thing is that I'm not sure how to transform an XMLGregorianCalendar to a SimpleDateFormat. Casting doesn't work, and the closest I can get is `XMLGregorianCalendar.toGregorianCalendar.getTime()` 
which returns a Date, but I can't find a way to transform a Date to a SimpleDateFormat type. Any ideas?

-EDIT- 
The reason why I like the SimpleDateFormat is because I can use the List of ISO 639-1 codes (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_ISO_639-1_codes), which is what I get from my context.

Comment: It would be great if you show how you consume this RESTful service and the class structure (if any).

Comment: You can't do that. `SimpleDateFormat` is an object that can **parse** dates from string and **format** dates to strings. But a `Date` object which holds the data bearing the meaning of a given point in time, is something entirely different.

Comment: A SimpleDateFormat formats a date.  It doesn't hold date data.

Comment: By "I need to localize the months depending on the language" do you mean having a localized string representing the date?

Comment: I need to localize the month, so for example, if locale is 'es', and month is 0 (zero-based months, of course), then the month would be 'Enero'.

Comment: Use `new Locale("es")`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't do that. `SimpleDateFormat` is an object that can **parse** dates from string and **format** dates to strings. But a [`Date`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html) object which holds the data bearing the meaning of a given point in time, is something entirely different.

However, you can use [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) to convert dates to strings:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf  = new SimpleDateFormat("YYYY-MMM-dd", myLocaleInstance);
System.out.println(sdf.format(myXMLGregorianCalendarInstance));
```

You just have to assemble the format string, and get the [Locale](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html) instance (for example from the language code).

#### Rules of thumb

- relying on default Locale  can mean bad trouble! (albeit unrelated here, the same applies to the default encoding too)
- `Date` does not have the time zone information, whereas `Calendar` does. Have to keep this in mind all the time, especially when dealing with webservices, providing and consuming data from all over the world...
- my personal favorite, which is slightly different, but can be ugly as hell: in Calendar, MONTHs are indexed from 0. So the month numbered 12 is not December, as jarnbjo stated...
- formatting objects are usually not thread safe. Using them in static variables is a bad smell! this is true for DecimalFormat too.

Comment: In Java, the default encoding is not related to the default locale. Calendars can have a month numbered 12 if the year has 13 months. There's even a constant for it in the Calendar class: UNDECIMBER.

Comment: @jarnbjo where did I write that there is correlation between the default locale and encoding? What I wrote is that both of them can have unwanated consequences. I didn't know about the month however...

Comment: You wrote that "relying on default Locale (and as such, the default encoding)" which is neither correct nor if it were, relevant to the question.

Comment: @jarnbjo I should have read what I wrote... One day, I might just learn English... I updated that bit. But regarding the question of (ir)relevance: I think adding information about common issues that bear the slightest similarity with the issue at hand can help. And default encoding can not be repeated enough to not cause issues...

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you should convert the `XMLGregorianCalendar` instance to a `Date` object and create a `Locale` object for the desired language:

```
Date date = xmlCalendar.toGregorianCalendar().getTime();        
Locale locale = new Locale("es");
```

You can then either use `SimpleDateFormat` to get the month's name in the specified language:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM", locale);        
System.out.println(sdf.format(date));
```

Will output: septiembre

Or you can get a localized date formatter to output the entire date using the specified language:

```
System.out.println(DateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.LONG, locale).format(date));
```

Will output: 11 de septiembre de 2013